# Convert content of UIScrollView in UIImage

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimage, photolibrary

In my application, users can add `UIImageView` as subview of my `UIScrollView`. When the user taps "Save" button, I want to save all the content of my `UIScrollView` as an `UIImage` into the photo library.

I've been looking on Google but there is not much on the subject.

Edit: the below code does the job

```
        CGRect rect = self.mainView.frame;
        [self.mainView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 824, self.mainView.contentSize.height)];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainView.bounds.size);
        [self.mainView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image , nil, nil, nil);
        [self.mainView setFrame:rect];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need to take screen shot of screen, you can try out this code on done action -

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[data writeToFile:@"myImage.png" atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Don't forget to resize the scroll view to fit the content before rendering, then resizing it back to its original size.

Comment: I got this error with the second line:
`Receiver type 'CALayer' for instance message is a forward declaration`

Comment: add this - #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: Thanks a lot rishi and Leo Natan